# running python script in bash slower than running code in IDLE

Tags: python

I have written a python script to draw the sierpinski gasket using Tkinter and when run from the python IDLE the program takes about half the time it takes to run when run from bash. I timed the script using them time module in python. Any ideas as to why this is happening will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: It probably has something to do with Tkinter already being in use when you use IDLE. I don't think this would hold up with non-Tkinter applications.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the way you're passing it. Based on your comment on the other answer, you're using `python -c`, and in IDLE you're using the Run command (or something similar). I'm not aware of any performance issues with `python -c`, but using Run in IDLE to run somescript.py is equivalent to `python somescript.py`.

You really should run scripts using `python -c`, it's more for small snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Rafe is likely correct - you can test this out by limiting your imports and seeing if that makes a difference in startup time. I.e., if you are doing

`from Tkinter import *`

then change that to import only the modules you actually need. Or write a quick null program that just sets up and tears down without using anything in the package - that should run pretty close to the same in both.

Comment: If anything, IDLE will run more slowly.

Comment: its kind of funny but when i change the script to an executable and run from the command line, it takes about the same time as when run from the IDLE. When the script is run by explicitly passing it as as argument to the interpreter in the commandline, it takes twice the amount of time again.

Comment: thanks alot guys for your time..running the script with the cprofiler from the commandline was when the time spiked so I am guessing that the cprofiler was adding overhead to the script excution time.